# Autowiring String property through application context

Tags: spring

I want to autowire a String bean as below

```
<bean id="name" class="java.lang.String" autowire="byName">
        <constructor-arg value="Aravind"/>
</bean>
<bean id="employee" class="Employee" autowire="byName"/>

public Class Employee
{
   private String name;
   public void setName(String name)
   {
     this.name=name;
    }
   public String getName()
   {
     return name;
   }
}
```

When I try to access the name attribute in the employee is null

```
Employee emp=(Employee)getApplicationContext().getBean("employee");
System.out.println(emp.getName()==null);
```

It prints true.

Can someone help on this?

Answer (score 1):

You still need to set the property on the `Employee` somehow.

Setting the name can be done in multiple ways.

#### XML configuration.

```
<bean id="employee" class="Employee" autowire="byName">
    <property name="name">
        <ref bean="name" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

#### Using `@Autowired`

```
public Class Employee {
   @Autowired
   private String name;

   public void setName(String name) {
     this.name=name;
   }

   public String getName() {
     return name;
   }
}
```